# Best way to prevent unused properties from being passed from object

Tags: c#, wcf, object

I'm putting together a WCF service that handles a large search (currently 50-60 parameters, with more likely to be added in the future). To handle this, I have a Search object with all the criteria which will be passed to the service in a message object. While all the search parameters must be available, it is often the case that 2-3 of the parameters receive user input and the others are null. To my mind, it doesn't make sense to pass the entire object around through every method if only a few fields are used. I'm looking for a technique that will extract the fields that are used with their values, which can then be validated and passed to the data layer to execute the search. A few ways to accomplish this that I can think of include:

- Use reflection to loop through the properties, and add non-null properties to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. The problem that comes to mind here is that I lose the type of the search parameter, which means the data layer search function will be one giant case statement with hard-coded cast values for each potential field. This seems to be overkill and creating way too tight of coupling.
- Create a SearchValue class with Name, Value, and System.Type properties, and use reflection to build a `List<SearchValue>`. This still results in a big case check in the search, but rather than by property it would be by type. This has some appeal in making the process more "generic" (i.e., independent of what combination of search values are used), but it also feels like I'm reinventing the wheel.

What pros and cons am I missing with these techniques? Is there a better way to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works for this line of communication, but possibly the [EmitDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx) property on the DataMemberAttribute?

Comment: Figures there would be a straightforward way to do it. This solves the "part 2" I mentioned in the other comment - this will remove anything not used client side, simplifying the data across the wire. So then we're back to what to do server-side - should I just not care about the empty fields, dump the SearchCriteria object to the data layer and let it parse it out? Or is there any benefit to just extracting the non-default value fields and passing only that to the data layer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ClientSide vs. Server Side. This will, in effect, drop fields not being used from being transmitted over the wire. Assuming you have the contract on the client, the client only sends "populated" fields to the service. The service then, assuming it has the same flags on the response object, will do the same. Is this not what you're after (with very minimal, and much integrated, effort?)

Comment: EmitDefaultValue doesn't change the structure of the actual Search object though, right? It only changes what's passed back and forth over the wire. So when the client sends the non-default valued data to the service, a full Search object is instantiated with the data sent across for given fields, plus default values for the remaining, correct? It's not going to create Search objects with different structures...that strikes me as a nightmare to program around. (continued next)

Comment: So if my read is correct, there could be one search param coming to the service, and service-side there will be a Search object created with one value and x amount of default values, which gets back to my original question. Is there any value in just trying to extract that one (or minimal) amount of values before sending the search request to the data layer, or at that point, is it not worth the effort and a better move just to dump the full Search object to the data layer for parsing?

Comment: It's my understanding that you're offering the client all the parameters to search by. It's then their prerogative to use any or all of those fields to filter with, which is then sent to the server to be used accordingly. Now, whether you parse out the "pertinent" information yourself, or let only the populated fields go across the wire, you still (at time of filtering) need to check which fields need to be applied and actually apply them. (con't)

Comment: A dictionary of these values isn't of any gain because you still need to anticipate every option (regardless if it was supplied). I say let the service layer handle minimizing traffic and you just worry about going through all the properties and either use or disregard them. It's essentially the same as instantiating the object with an empty construct and .NET populating them with empty values (then filling in the populatedfields later with data that it _did_ receive).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with passing the whole object around is possible between client and service, when there are too many empty xml nodes in serialized request making it bigger then necessary. Are you trying to handle this? I would say that anyway it is not a big deal and is not worth inventing complicated custom mechanisms.

Comment: That's the next part of my question that I'm noodling over right now - even if there's a logical way to do this, which side does it make more sense to do this on? As you point out, lots of empty nodes = larger request than necessary, so client side makes sense. Downside there is moving the overhead for reflection to the client side rather than on the server. On the flip side, if the full object is passed, is there any benefit to simplifying it at that point? There's an argument to be made that doing it server side allows for addition and removal of parameters easier.

Answer (score 0):

In your first point you mention using `Reflection` to convert your type to a `Dictionary`. And on the other side, why not write a reverse logic to convert the `Dictionary` back to your type using `Reflection` again?

### Example:

`Client Side` > `YourType` >>(`Reflection`)>> `Dictionary` > Channel > `Dictionary` >>(`Reflection`)>> `YourType` > `Server Side`

Answer (score 0):

A few options come to my mind:

- Use codegen to create the packing/unpacking code into and out of a Dictionary.  The generator code would use reflection, but the packing/unpacking code would not.
- Split your Search class into multiple smaller classes, then have your Search class reference those.  Don't instantiate the child classes if those search parameters aren't being used.  Perhaps something like:
- - Search
- - - New class containing some common fields
- - - New class containing some other fields

Answer (score 0):

Have a dataContract class with optional datamember.

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

`public int salary = 0;`

DataContract serializer ignore such member when value is default.

MSDN recommendation:
Setting the EmitDefaultValue property to false is not recommended. You should do this only if there is a specific need to do so, such as for interoperability or data size reduction.

You do also have property IsRequired in DataMember, setting it to false and EmitDefaultValue with help reducing transport and serialization overhead.